# i have install ubuntu 22.04.2 in amd ryzen 5 7000 series with amd radeon graphics, not fully compatible

Tags: wireless, keyboard, touchpad

The keyboard response is too slow as well as the wifi option is also not showing. sometime touchpad is not working

Comment: It seems I have the same issue. I haven't been able to resolve it yet, so running Windows which is very inconvenient to may day-to-day tasks